# What is the address of main() and how many bytes does it allocate on the stack for its frame size?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, gdb, dynamic-analysis, objdump

Here is my `objdump -d` output but I do not know where to look. I understand assembly but it is a little confusing trying to find out what the values of registers are at certain points.  If anyone knows how to do this in IDA I have the free version of IDA 5.0.

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# objdump -d dbgLab.bin 

dbgLab.bin:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .init:

08048374 <.init>:
 8048374:   53                      push   %ebx
 8048375:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8048378:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   804837d <printf@plt-0x43>
 804837d:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 804837e:   81 c3 77 1c 00 00       add    $0x1c77,%ebx
 8048384:   8b 83 fc ff ff ff       mov    -0x4(%ebx),%eax
 804838a:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 804838c:   74 05                   je     8048393 <printf@plt-0x2d>
 804838e:   e8 5d 00 00 00          call   80483f0 <__gmon_start__@plt>
 8048393:   e8 48 01 00 00          call   80484e0 <strncmp@plt+0xa0>
 8048398:   e8 13 03 00 00          call   80486b0 <strncmp@plt+0x270>
 804839d:   83 c4 08                add    $0x8,%esp
 80483a0:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80483a1:   c3                      ret    

Disassembly of section .plt:

080483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>:
 80483b0:   ff 35 f8 9f 04 08       pushl  0x8049ff8
 80483b6:   ff 25 fc 9f 04 08       jmp    *0x8049ffc
 80483bc:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
    ...

080483c0 <printf@plt>:
 80483c0:   ff 25 00 a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a000
 80483c6:   68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
 80483cb:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

080483d0 <malloc@plt>:
 80483d0:   ff 25 04 a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a004
 80483d6:   68 08 00 00 00          push   $0x8
 80483db:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

080483e0 <puts@plt>:
 80483e0:   ff 25 08 a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a008
 80483e6:   68 10 00 00 00          push   $0x10
 80483eb:   e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

080483f0 <__gmon_start__@plt>:
 80483f0:   ff 25 0c a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a00c
 80483f6:   68 18 00 00 00          push   $0x18
 80483fb:   e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

08048400 <exit@plt>:
 8048400:   ff 25 10 a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a010
 8048406:   68 20 00 00 00          push   $0x20
 804840b:   e9 a0 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

08048410 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
 8048410:   ff 25 14 a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a014
 8048416:   68 28 00 00 00          push   $0x28
 804841b:   e9 90 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

08048420 <strncpy@plt>:
 8048420:   ff 25 18 a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a018
 8048426:   68 30 00 00 00          push   $0x30
 804842b:   e9 80 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

08048430 <atoi@plt>:
 8048430:   ff 25 1c a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a01c
 8048436:   68 38 00 00 00          push   $0x38
 804843b:   e9 70 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

08048440 <strncmp@plt>:
 8048440:   ff 25 20 a0 04 08       jmp    *0x804a020
 8048446:   68 40 00 00 00          push   $0x40
 804844b:   e9 60 ff ff ff          jmp    80483b0 <printf@plt-0x10>

Disassembly of section .text:

08048450 <.text>:
 8048450:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
 8048452:   5e                      pop    %esi
 8048453:   89 e1                   mov    %esp,%ecx
 8048455:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048458:   50                      push   %eax
 8048459:   54                      push   %esp
 804845a:   52                      push   %edx
 804845b:   68 a0 86 04 08          push   $0x80486a0
 8048460:   68 30 86 04 08          push   $0x8048630
 8048465:   51                      push   %ecx
 8048466:   56                      push   %esi
 8048467:   68 3e 85 04 08          push   $0x804853e
 804846c:   e8 9f ff ff ff          call   8048410 <__libc_start_main@plt>
 8048471:   f4                      hlt    
 8048472:   90                      nop
 8048473:   90                      nop
 8048474:   90                      nop
 8048475:   90                      nop
 8048476:   90                      nop
 8048477:   90                      nop
 8048478:   90                      nop
 8048479:   90                      nop
 804847a:   90                      nop
 804847b:   90                      nop
 804847c:   90                      nop
 804847d:   90                      nop
 804847e:   90                      nop
 804847f:   90                      nop
 8048480:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048481:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048483:   53                      push   %ebx
 8048484:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 8048487:   80 3d 44 a0 04 08 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x804a044
 804848e:   75 3f                   jne    80484cf <strncmp@plt+0x8f>
 8048490:   a1 48 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a048,%eax
 8048495:   bb 20 9f 04 08          mov    $0x8049f20,%ebx
 804849a:   81 eb 1c 9f 04 08       sub    $0x8049f1c,%ebx
 80484a0:   c1 fb 02                sar    $0x2,%ebx
 80484a3:   83 eb 01                sub    $0x1,%ebx
 80484a6:   39 d8                   cmp    %ebx,%eax
 80484a8:   73 1e                   jae    80484c8 <strncmp@plt+0x88>
 80484aa:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
 80484b0:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 80484b3:   a3 48 a0 04 08          mov    %eax,0x804a048
 80484b8:   ff 14 85 1c 9f 04 08    call   *0x8049f1c(,%eax,4)
 80484bf:   a1 48 a0 04 08          mov    0x804a048,%eax
 80484c4:   39 d8                   cmp    %ebx,%eax
 80484c6:   72 e8                   jb     80484b0 <strncmp@plt+0x70>
 80484c8:   c6 05 44 a0 04 08 01    movb   $0x1,0x804a044
 80484cf:   83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
 80484d2:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80484d3:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 80484d4:   c3                      ret    
 80484d5:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 80484d9:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
 80484e0:   55                      push   %ebp
 80484e1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80484e3:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
 80484e6:   a1 24 9f 04 08          mov    0x8049f24,%eax
 80484eb:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 80484ed:   74 12                   je     8048501 <strncmp@plt+0xc1>
 80484ef:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 80484f4:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 80484f6:   74 09                   je     8048501 <strncmp@plt+0xc1>
 80484f8:   c7 04 24 24 9f 04 08    movl   $0x8049f24,(%esp)
 80484ff:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
 8048501:   c9                      leave  
 8048502:   c3                      ret    
 8048503:   90                      nop
 8048504:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048505:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048507:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
 804850a:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 804850d:   88 45 ec                mov    %al,-0x14(%ebp)
 8048510:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
 8048517:   eb 1b                   jmp    8048534 <strncmp@plt+0xf4>
 8048519:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
 804851c:   03 45 0c                add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 804851f:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edx
 8048522:   03 55 0c                add    0xc(%ebp),%edx
 8048525:   0f b6 0a                movzbl (%edx),%ecx
 8048528:   0f b6 55 ec             movzbl -0x14(%ebp),%edx
 804852c:   31 ca                   xor    %ecx,%edx
 804852e:   88 10                   mov    %dl,(%eax)
 8048530:   83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
 8048534:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
 8048537:   3b 45 10                cmp    0x10(%ebp),%eax
 804853a:   7c dd                   jl     8048519 <strncmp@plt+0xd9>
 804853c:   c9                      leave  
 804853d:   c3                      ret    
 804853e:   55                      push   %ebp
 804853f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048541:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048544:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
 8048547:   c6 44 24 1f cf          movb   $0xcf,0x1f(%esp)
 804854c:   c7 04 24 0d 00 00 00    movl   $0xd,(%esp)
 8048553:   e8 78 fe ff ff          call   80483d0 <malloc@plt>
 8048558:   89 44 24 18             mov    %eax,0x18(%esp)
 804855c:   83 7d 08 02             cmpl   $0x2,0x8(%ebp)
 8048560:   7f 0c                   jg     804856e <strncmp@plt+0x12e>
 8048562:   c7 04 24 ff ff ff ff    movl   $0xffffffff,(%esp)
 8048569:   e8 92 fe ff ff          call   8048400 <exit@plt>
 804856e:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048571:   83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 8048574:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 8048576:   c7 44 24 08 0d 00 00    movl   $0xd,0x8(%esp)
 804857d:   00 
 804857e:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048582:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 8048586:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048589:   e8 92 fe ff ff          call   8048420 <strncpy@plt>
 804858e:   0f b6 44 24 1f          movzbl 0x1f(%esp),%eax
 8048593:   c7 44 24 08 0c 00 00    movl   $0xc,0x8(%esp)
 804859a:   00 
 804859b:   c7 44 24 04 30 a0 04    movl   $0x804a030,0x4(%esp)
 80485a2:   08 
 80485a3:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80485a6:   e8 59 ff ff ff          call   8048504 <strncmp@plt+0xc4>
 80485ab:   c7 44 24 08 14 00 00    movl   $0x14,0x8(%esp)
 80485b2:   00 
 80485b3:   8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
 80485b7:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 80485bb:   c7 04 24 30 a0 04 08    movl   $0x804a030,(%esp)
 80485c2:   e8 79 fe ff ff          call   8048440 <strncmp@plt>
 80485c7:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 80485c9:   74 21                   je     80485ec <strncmp@plt+0x1ac>
 80485cb:   b8 08 87 04 08          mov    $0x8048708,%eax
 80485d0:   c7 44 24 04 30 a0 04    movl   $0x804a030,0x4(%esp)
 80485d7:   08 
 80485d8:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80485db:   e8 e0 fd ff ff          call   80483c0 <printf@plt>
 80485e0:   c7 04 24 ff ff ff ff    movl   $0xffffffff,(%esp)
 80485e7:   e8 14 fe ff ff          call   8048400 <exit@plt>
 80485ec:   8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 80485ef:   83 c0 08                add    $0x8,%eax
 80485f2:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 80485f4:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80485f7:   e8 34 fe ff ff          call   8048430 <atoi@plt>
 80485fc:   8b 15 40 a0 04 08       mov    0x804a040,%edx
 8048602:   39 d0                   cmp    %edx,%eax
 8048604:   74 18                   je     804861e <strncmp@plt+0x1de>
 8048606:   c7 04 24 16 87 04 08    movl   $0x8048716,(%esp)
 804860d:   e8 ce fd ff ff          call   80483e0 <puts@plt>
 8048612:   c7 04 24 ff ff ff ff    movl   $0xffffffff,(%esp)
 8048619:   e8 e2 fd ff ff          call   8048400 <exit@plt>
 804861e:   c7 04 24 1b 87 04 08    movl   $0x804871b,(%esp)
 8048625:   e8 b6 fd ff ff          call   80483e0 <puts@plt>
 804862a:   c9                      leave  
 804862b:   c3                      ret    
 804862c:   90                      nop
 804862d:   90                      nop
 804862e:   90                      nop
 804862f:   90                      nop
 8048630:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048631:   57                      push   %edi
 8048632:   56                      push   %esi
 8048633:   53                      push   %ebx
 8048634:   e8 69 00 00 00          call   80486a2 <strncmp@plt+0x262>
 8048639:   81 c3 bb 19 00 00       add    $0x19bb,%ebx
 804863f:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
 8048642:   8b 6c 24 30             mov    0x30(%esp),%ebp
 8048646:   8d bb 20 ff ff ff       lea    -0xe0(%ebx),%edi
 804864c:   e8 23 fd ff ff          call   8048374 <printf@plt-0x4c>
 8048651:   8d 83 20 ff ff ff       lea    -0xe0(%ebx),%eax
 8048657:   29 c7                   sub    %eax,%edi
 8048659:   c1 ff 02                sar    $0x2,%edi
 804865c:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
 804865e:   74 29                   je     8048689 <strncmp@plt+0x249>
 8048660:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
 8048662:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
 8048668:   8b 44 24 38             mov    0x38(%esp),%eax
 804866c:   89 2c 24                mov    %ebp,(%esp)
 804866f:   89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048673:   8b 44 24 34             mov    0x34(%esp),%eax
 8048677:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 804867b:   ff 94 b3 20 ff ff ff    call   *-0xe0(%ebx,%esi,4)
 8048682:   83 c6 01                add    $0x1,%esi
 8048685:   39 fe                   cmp    %edi,%esi
 8048687:   75 df                   jne    8048668 <strncmp@plt+0x228>
 8048689:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
 804868c:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 804868d:   5e                      pop    %esi
 804868e:   5f                      pop    %edi
 804868f:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048690:   c3                      ret    
 8048691:   eb 0d                   jmp    80486a0 <strncmp@plt+0x260>
 8048693:   90                      nop
 8048694:   90                      nop
 8048695:   90                      nop
 8048696:   90                      nop
 8048697:   90                      nop
 8048698:   90                      nop
 8048699:   90                      nop
 804869a:   90                      nop
 804869b:   90                      nop
 804869c:   90                      nop
 804869d:   90                      nop
 804869e:   90                      nop
 804869f:   90                      nop
 80486a0:   f3 c3                   repz ret 
 80486a2:   8b 1c 24                mov    (%esp),%ebx
 80486a5:   c3                      ret    
 80486a6:   90                      nop
 80486a7:   90                      nop
 80486a8:   90                      nop
 80486a9:   90                      nop
 80486aa:   90                      nop
 80486ab:   90                      nop
 80486ac:   90                      nop
 80486ad:   90                      nop
 80486ae:   90                      nop
 80486af:   90                      nop
 80486b0:   55                      push   %ebp
 80486b1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80486b3:   53                      push   %ebx
 80486b4:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 80486b7:   a1 14 9f 04 08          mov    0x8049f14,%eax
 80486bc:   83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 80486bf:   74 13                   je     80486d4 <strncmp@plt+0x294>
 80486c1:   bb 14 9f 04 08          mov    $0x8049f14,%ebx
 80486c6:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
 80486c8:   83 eb 04                sub    $0x4,%ebx
 80486cb:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
 80486cd:   8b 03                   mov    (%ebx),%eax
 80486cf:   83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 80486d2:   75 f4                   jne    80486c8 <strncmp@plt+0x288>
 80486d4:   83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
 80486d7:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80486d8:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 80486d9:   c3                      ret    
 80486da:   90                      nop
 80486db:   90                      nop

Disassembly of section .fini:

080486dc <.fini>:
 80486dc:   53                      push   %ebx
 80486dd:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 80486e0:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   80486e5 <strncmp@plt+0x2a5>
 80486e5:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80486e6:   81 c3 0f 19 00 00       add    $0x190f,%ebx
 80486ec:   e8 8f fd ff ff          call   8048480 <strncmp@plt+0x40>
 80486f1:   83 c4 08                add    $0x8,%esp
 80486f4:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 80486f5:   c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 4):

Address of `main` is the first argument to the `__libc_start_main` function. Let's look at the entrypoint code:

```
 xor    %ebp,%ebp
 pop    %esi
 mov    %esp,%ecx
 and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 push   %eax
 push   %esp
 push   %edx
 push   $0x80486a0
 push   $0x8048630
 push   %ecx
 push   %esi
 push   $0x804853e
 call   8048410 <__libc_start_main@plt>
 hlt
```

Since it's x86 code, it uses cdecl ABI, which means the first argument is pushed last onto the stack. So the address of `main` is `0x804853e`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this works if the program implements a C-like `main` function. Unfortunately, some programs don't and all you have is the entry point.

Answer (score 2):

Well, from the `objdump` listing you provided it's pretty obvious that this binary file has been stripped out of all symbols. This is why you won't be able to find the `main` symbol or any other function's symbol but those originating from an external library. But, given that this binary file is an ELF, you can run the `readelf -h` command on it and get the `Entry point address` which will certainly point to the `.text` section located at address `08048450` in your binary's `objdump` listing.

If you'd like more information on how to find the `main` function, the answers of [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/how-to-find-main-in-binary) post & [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/reversing-elf-64-bit-lsb-executable-x86-64-gdb/3816#3816) post cover most of what you need to know.